# Define URL Endpoint in Struts for Scraper

Tags: java, python, django, xmlhttprequest, struts

Here's the current basic set-up: Python 2 on Django, Selenium & BeautifulSoup, MqSQL (working on replacing Chrome with PhantomJS to reduce memory usage)

I built a search engine. Upon a user entering search criteria, I fill in forms based on the query, scrape the data from said sources, using my algorithm to sort and organize the data, and displays the results to the user.

This has been pretty slow due to numerous requests (over 1,000) to the websites' servers to retrieve data (usually takes about 90s for search results to start to display).

[image]
[image]

I'm now reworking my scrapers with the goal to decrease the time between submitting the search and displaying the search results. I need to combine all of those requests into 1 or 2 requests and redesign my scrapers to be as server-side as possible (i.e. using xhr) to increase speed for search results to display.

On some websites, I can easily manipulate forms using the URL structure directly and overall avoid web drivers (except afaik pagination). However, I've come across a few websites using Struts (versions 1 and 2) and can't figure out the endpoints to work with. I haven't touched Java at all in ages and am no-longer familiar with it's structure.

Does anyone know how to work with scraping a site built with struts using server-side manipulation instead of slow web drivers? Is this even possible?